# Credit card expiration month is shown as 00 on confirmation screens and receipts

Tags: payment-processor, receipts, confirmation

It seems the expiration date for credit cards is being displayed incorrectly as 00 YYYY (as in, it always shows 00 no matter what the actual input is) on event and contribution confirmation screens, thank you screens and in email receipts.

I can't replicate this on dmaster or locally. No errors logged and nothing in the console. Doesn't matter which payment processor is in use. Payments are still processed as usual. Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

[image]

5.56.2 on D7.

Comment: There was something similar but not really the same: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4012. But what timezone?

Comment: Doesn't seem related to timezone (tried the same locally with the same timezone and not getting this issue). America/Edmonton (only the Yukon got rid of DST, the rest of us just said we were going to and then didn't).

Comment: Hehe don't get me started on DST...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is ... check your date formats carefully because maybe you made a mistake entering them and never noticed. Pretty obvious!